# map showing blur when i load the static map

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

when i load the static map using the URL, the map is displaying but its too much blur....kindly give the solution friends...Thanks in advance..........
Here is my code...

```
    public class UpdateMap extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... value) {

            Double latter = Double.parseDouble(value[0]);
            Double longer = Double.parseDouble(value[1]);
            String address = value[2];

            try {

                String mapurl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
                        + latter
                        + ","
                        + longer

                        + "&zoom=15&size=100x100&sensor=true&markersize=55&markers=color:red%7Clabel:%7C"
                        + latter + "," + longer;

                double lat1 = Double.valueOf(latter);

                double longt1 = Double.valueOf(longer);

                Bitmap mapimage = BitmapConvert.bitmaptobitmap(application
                        .getGoogleMapThumbnail(lat1, longt1, mapurl));

                Bitmap crop = crop(mapimage);

                String mapimagestring = BitmapConvert.bitmaptostring(crop);

                chatHistoryDB.updatemapimage(latter + "/" + longer + "/"
                        + address, mapimagestring);

                chatAdapter.doubletick();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Usually when this happens, the map is still being loaded or the higher resolution image is not being loaded for whatever reason.

Comment: @erad i checked with that it was still like that even after fully loaded

Comment: Is the imageView you're loading your image to larger than 100x100 pixels? You might be scaling a tiny image to a larger image, which may pixelate things.

Comment: @erad yes, but i can get only a blur map even before scaling

Comment: Does it give you the same results if you change location? I am able to get a pretty decent map of a city using the URL you're using. Though it's extremely small, so personally I would change the `size=100x100`

Comment: @erad i ll set tat into image view so that this size, for example if u send the location in wats app it ll give the clear picture of that map but in my map view it is not giving accuracy its very much blur